# Is there a keyboard shortcut in Pycharm for renaming a specific variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, keyboard, pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using **Pycharm** for Python coding, and I want to change the name of a **specific variable** all over the code. is there any keyboard shortcut for this operation?

In Matlab I can use *ctrl* + *shift*.

For example:

```
old_name=5
x=old_name*123
```

will become:

```
new_name=5
x=new_name*123
```

without the need to change both of the `old_name` references.

Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Highlight your `old_name` and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about a shortcut for this special purpose, but I simply use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to replace the old variable names with new ones. You can also set settings such as *Match case*, *Regex* or *In selection*.

Note that this won't work, if you have a variable name including another variable name:

```
var1 = 0
var1_s = "0"
```

Replacing `var1` to `xy` would result in :

```
xy = 0
xy_s = "0"
```

But that also forces you to do consistent and clear variable naming.

Comment: Using Ctrl+R might change some unwanted sentences. As an example: if I would replace 'var' with 'xy', a comment with the sentence: "the variable which count the animals" would become: "the *xyiable* which count the animals". etc.

Comment: @roishik You’re absolutely right, that’s a very naive approach. Seems like I didn’t knew any better back then, but I’m afraid I can’t delete my answer - I certainly would...