# PyCharm: How to effectively rename a variable in all places where it occurs in a module at the same time?

Tags: pycharm, rename

Given the following Python code

```
a = 3 # only this variable is going to be renamed by hand

A = 3  
abc = 3 
a += 1
```

I want to rename all occurrences of the variable "a" to "b" automatically so that the result looks like this

```
b = 3 # variable was renamed from a to b manually

A = 3   # variable was not affected by the renaming
abc = 3 # variable was not affected by the renaming
b += 1  # variable was renamed from a to b automatically
```

Notice that I just want to rename the variables in the **current module**, nowhere else!

At the moment, to do this I am doing the following steps (Pycharm 2018.3.3 (Community Edition)):

1. Place the cursor on the variable I want to rename.
2. Open the renaming dialog via `Shift+F6` and make sure that the checkbox
   "Search in comments and strings" is unchecked (see image of rename dialog).
3. Type in the new name of the variable.
4. Press `Enter` to refactor.

[image: rename dialog]

The problems with this method are:

1. The "Looking for Usages" process (see image below) **takes like forever** for some variable names (**renaming "a" to "b" takes about 27 seconds!!!**).
   [image: Looking for Usages porcess]
2. Occurences of the variable in **comments are not renamed**.

With this being said, my final question is:
Is there a way to rename variables that is **fast regardless of the variable name** and **only takes place in the current module**?

Comment: There is already an answer to this. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39746405/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-in-pycharm-for-renaming-a-specific-variable)

Comment: As @Shub pointed out, you can just use `Shift + F6` I do not understand your qualms that "It takes a lot of actions". In both Matlab and Pycharm you 1) Highlight variable 2) Press a combination of 2 whole keys simultaneously!! 3) Type a new variable name. 4) Press `Enter`. How is this process somehow more tedious/confusing because it is in PyCharm?

Comment: @Shub `Shift+F6` is not fast regardless of the variable name. Renaming of "a" to "b" e.g. takes much longer than it should. Im searching for a way to rename variables that is fast regardless of the variable name. This is not answered in the post you linked

Comment: @Reedinationer Yeah, you are right. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @zwithouta sounds good! I think you are misunderstanding the feature discussed in your blockquote though. I've used this feature extensively when I ported my scripts to PyCharm and all it does is suggest a variable name that meets coding standards. For instance if I had a variable `SomthingInCamelCase` and went to use this feature all it does is recommend `something_in_camel_case` (nothing else) and I can quickly press down arrow -> tab to select it. You probably think it's not working because `a` or `b` are very simple and it wouldn't have any better suggestions for you.

Comment: @Reedinationer Ah ok! I see. Then this feature has nothing to do with my question. I removed that part from my post.

Comment: So I'm also not clear on the "only takes place in the current module" bit. When I use `Shift + F6` it is smart enough that it only renames within the namespace (it will only search a specific function for local variables, or only consider the global variables) of the current script. I am on default settings, so I'd think that if it is renaming everything within an entire module that you have toggled some "extensive search" setting and that is likely tied to it taking so long as well

Comment: @Reedinationer The "only takes place in the current module" bit is added for the case that somebody comes up with a solution that allows renaming all kind of variable names fast, but does so across different modules. By the way, why does renaming take place across modules when the 'Search in comments and strings' option in the renaming dialogue is activated? According to the name of this option, I would have expected nothing to change in the behavior of the renaming, except that comments and strings are also searched for the inputted variable name.

Comment: I do not know. In my installation of PyCharm when I toggle "search in comments and strings" it (as expected) just searches the current script and also searches in the comments and strings of the script...Did you change settings while fiddling with it that may have impacted this perhaps?

Comment: Hm, not that I know of. I'll make a new question for this. Thanks for your advise!

Comment: done. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003335859-How-can-I-search-in-comments-and-strings-for-the-current-module-only-

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this in Pycharm 2019.1. However, Jetbrains has had a rename performance issue on another of their products.  I would suggest opening a bug report with Jetbrains. https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2018/12/27/rider-2018-3-1-bug-fix-update/

Answer (score 0):

You can edit it using the refactor tool in Pycharm.
Click on the variable and press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>.

[image: Rafactor dialog box screenshot]

Type the name and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.